# Magento API V2 - WSDL and associative multi arrays

Tags: arrays, web-services, api, magento, wsdl

I extended the Magento V2 API and therefore created a wsdl.xml. My webservice returns a associative multi array. I googled a little bit and found two definitions of complex types:

```
<complexType name="associativeMultiArray">
    <all>
        <element name="associativeArray" type="typens:associativeArray" minOccurs="0" />
    </all>
</complexType>
<complexType name="stringArray">
    <all>
        <element name="multi_data" type="typens:associativeMultiArray" minOccurs="0" />
    </all>
</complexType>

<message name="methodResponse">
    <part name="result" type="typens:stringArray" />
</message>
```

The other one:

```
<complexType name="associativeMultiArray">
    <complexContent>
        <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="typens:associativeMultiEntity[]"/>
        </restriction>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<complexType name="associativeMultiEntity">
    <all>
        <element name="key" type="xsd:string"/>
        <element name="value" type="typens:ArrayOfString"/>
    </all>
</complexType>

<complexType name="ArrayOfString">
    <complexContent>
        <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <attribute ref="soapenc:arrayType" wsdl:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
        </restriction>
    </complexContent>
</complexType>

<message name="methodResponse">
    <part name="result" type="typens:associativeMultiArray" />
</message>
```

The problem is, none of these two works. If I output the result after the query I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
    )
)
```

It doesn't matter if I return `array('test)` or `array('key'=>'value')`, it is always the same output. Basically I have two questions:

- Are `ArrayOfString`, `associativeArray` and `associativeMultiArray` declarations of the following: `<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
          <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
              schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"/>` ?
- If I have very complex array structures like 10 dimensional associative arrays, do I have to declare every dimension in the wsdl.xml? How do I handle this? How does it work? Why don't the above declarations not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an exact solution to the question but I found another way how to solve this: Simply serialize the array as JSON with `json_encode` and decode it with `json_decode`. With this the array can be of any complexity. Returntype is then `xsd:string` in the wsdl.

Comment: FYI: `xsd:array` will work with an associative array, (and might work with multi-arrays, I'm not sure.) However, we've run into WSDL validation when using this.